# How to access context from a custom django-admin command?

Tags: python, django, django-4.0

I have been using django.text client to examine the context of some URLs from several unit tests with a code similar to the following:

```
from django.test import TestCase

class MyTests(TestCase):       

    def example_test(self):
        
        response = self.client.get('/')
        # I can access response.context at this point
```

Now I am trying to do the same thing from a [custom management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/custom-management-commands/) but surprisingly this is not working as expected as I can not access the context in the response object.

```
from django.test import Client

class Command(BaseCommand):

    def handle(self, *args, **kwargs):
        c = Client()
        response = c.get('/')
        # response.context is always None at this point
```

Is there a way to access the context from a custom management command?
(Django 4.0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Django test runner `DiscoverRunner` (and pytest's auto-use fixture `django_test_environment`) calls `setup_test_environment`, which [replaces Django `Template._render`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/6c0539e/django/test/utils.py#L147). `instrumented_test_render` sends the `template_rendered` signal that the Django test `Client` connects to to populate `data`, from which it then sets `response.context`.

You can do the same in your custom management command:

```py
from django.template import Template
from django.test.utils import instrumented_test_render

Template._render = instrumented_test_render
```

---

If you want to include all other patches used in tests, you can call `setup_test_environment`:

```py
from django.test.utils import setup_test_environment

setup_test_environment()
```

Among other things, `setup_test_environment` replaces `settings.EMAIL_BACKEND`:

> ```py
> settings.EMAIL_BACKEND = "django.core.mail.backends.locmem.EmailBackend"
>
> ...
>
> mail.outbox = []
> ```

Comment: Using setup_test_environment before using my client solved the issue